# Wordpress Function.php doesn't work where search.php when no results found

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing a custom Wordpress site, in Blog section i used the widget Wordpress sidebar, and when a use search widget to find a word that exist in the site, it works fine, but when i search for a missing word in the site, the side breaks, all the stylesheet and JS dont get included. In my point of view, when the search has no results, Wordpress dont "run" the `function.php`.

I found a similar question : ([wordpress sidebar loops wont work when in search.php when no results found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318375/wordpress-sidebar-loops-wont-work-when-in-search-php-when-no-results-found)).

But, even if I remove the `if`  it didnt work, stays the same.

CODE :

```
<div class="row" align="center" >
    <div class="container"> <div style="height: 60px;width: 100%"></div>    
        <h1 style="color: #087ba7;">Resulta da busca: <?php echo $s; ?></h1> 
    </div>
</div>

             <div class="row" align="center" >
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="span9">
                                <?php if(have_posts()): 
                                        while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                                            <div class="span9" style="text-align: left;margin-top: 50px;">
                                                <h1 style="font-size: 18.5px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
                                                <hr />
                                                <div class="span2 post_thumb div-img-circle">
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="span6" style="text-align: justify;">
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">

                                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div style="width: 100%;text-align: right">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Leia Mais</a>  
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                <?php   endwhile; ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
                                <div class="span9" style="text-align: left;margin-top: 50px;">
                                    <h1 style="font-size: 18.5px;"><?php echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' ); ?></h1> 
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2" style="text-align: left;">
                                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row" align="center" >
                        <div class="container"> 
                            <?php custom_pagination(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You will need to provide some more informations. The relevant parts of your code would help, for example.

Comment: Sorry i edit it with the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem.
I make a copy of twelve theme folder and copy the content of my custom files inside the same files in the new folder and it just work.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement may very well be the problem.  wp_reset_query() should only be used if you had to use query_posts() per the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query. Since query_posts isn't in the code you've shown, I'd assume this is the problem.

Comment: I remove it but it still look the same, the function.php isnt included when the search dont return any results

Comment: I make i few more tests and wordpress dont include anything inside <head> Tags, i code some Css inside the Dev and even this is imported in the page

Comment: I made another change, i comment all the if, leaving just the while and still got the problem, when searching a word that dont exist it loses all the code inside the <head>

Comment: I Also remove the While leaving only 

   <?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="container"> <div style="height: 60px;width: 100%"></div>
                <div style="width: 90%;text-align: left;margin-bottom: 100px;margin-top: 20px;" class="contentinfo">
                               <h1> Resultado da busca por: <?php echo $s; ?> </h1>
  </div>
 </div><!-- #primary -->
        </div>
<?php
get_footer();

And still got the problem